# Removing sidebar from product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I installed Woocommerce on top of Anariel theme. The problem that I'm having is the sidebar shows up on the listing page, and product detail page. I've tried a few things to remove but nothing seems to work. What should I be doing to remove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'disable_woo_commerce_sidebar' );

function disable_woo_commerce_sidebar() {
    if ( is_product() || is_shop() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
```

and if you want to hide the sidebar in all pages. try with the below code.

```
function disable_woo_commerce_sidebar() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10); 
}
add_action('init', 'disable_woo_commerce_sidebar');
```